# Can I use spatie/laravel-google-calendar for a web server application with multiple users?

Tags: laravel, google-calendar-api

I'm working on a Laravel site where users could connect their Google account and manage their Google calendars directly from within the site. I found https://github.com/spatie/laravel-google-calendar but I'm not sure that it really meets my needs.

That package doesn't seem to follow the authentication flow (OAuth 2) I'm used to with other APIs. It uses service accounts and stores credentials in JSON files where I usually save access and refresh tokens in my users table.

So am I missing something or is that package not made for that kind of site ?

Comment: Scroll down a little, to the section in the readme titled "Authentication with OAuth2".

Comment: Thank you. Yes I've seen that part but I don't understand of it allows me to manage multiple users. The config file of the package only refers one oauth/token_json file so where do I store all my users tokens ?

Comment: *Finally, for a more seamless experience in your application, instead of using the quickstart tool you can set up a consent screen in the Google API console. This would allow non-technical users of your application to easily generate their own tokens. This is completely optional.* I think this is what you need to do to follow the more traditional OAuth2 flow you're used to

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But could you please explain me how I can store multiple users credentials/tokens when that package config file only references one json file ?

Comment: I would imagine the package doesn't intend for this to be the use case i.e. it's more of an admin package to integrate a google calendar account with your website, not to manage each user's google calendar account. However you can always hack it a bit to dynamically set the [token_json](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-google-calendar/blob/master/config/google-calendar.php#L31) configuration value before using it so you can have a different file for each user but I don't think this is the intended use case for this package

Comment: Thanks @apokryfos I believe you are right which means the answer to my question is no, you can't use the package to deal with multiple users, unless you hack it. That package seems great so it's a shame they didn't allow for that use case. I'll code it myself then.